# Reading values from excel as floats using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I am reading values from an excel document and using them for computation. However am having a problem reading the values as floats.
For instance if I try adding up y and z am getting  an error message that it could not be converted from string to float.
Attached is the error message [The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my1gU.jpg)   and the sample of data am trying to read from

[Sample excel document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUWNo.jpg)

Comment: Please copy and paste your code, error message, and the sample data here.

Comment: There's a space between 2 and 0, so the float() function couldn't work. You should do: `float('2 019.08'.replace(' ', ''))`